# module 'notebook' has no attribute 'nbextensions' on vscode

Tags: python, vpython, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I'm running Jupiter on vscode, and trying to run a graph animation with vpython.
but when I run this:

```
from vpython import graph, canvas
scene = canvas()
g1 = graph(xtitle="x", ytitle="y", width=500, height=250)
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Documents\quantum tunneling.ipynb Cell 8 line 2
      1 scene = canvas()
----> 2 g1 = graph(xtitle="x", ytitle="y", width=500, height=250)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py:2370, in graph.__init__(self, **args)
   2368 def __init__(self, **args):
   2369     objName = 'graph'
-> 2370     super(graph,self).__init__()
   2372 ## default values
   2373     self._width = 640

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py:257, in baseObj.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    254 if not (baseObj._view_constructed or
    255         baseObj._canvas_constructing):
    256     if _isnotebook:
--> 257         from .with_notebook import _
    258     else:
    259         from .no_notebook import _

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\vpython\with_notebook.py:80
     77         transfer = (v != __version__) # need not transfer files to nbextensions if correct version's files already there
     79 if transfer:
---> 80     notebook.nbextensions.install_nbextension(path = package_dir+"/vpython_data",overwrite = True,user = True,verbose = 0)
     81     notebook.nbextensions.install_nbextension(path = package_dir+"/vpython_libraries",overwrite = True,user = True,verbose = 0)
     83     # Wait for files to be transferred to nbextensions:

AttributeError: module 'notebook' has no attribute 'nbextensions'
```

I tried reinstalling the extensions:
`pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

and enabling it:
`jupyter nbextension enable codefolding/main`

I can see the 'nbextensions.py' file inside my \Python311\site-packages\notebook path.

So I don't understand why it's not recognizing it.

Comment: I run `mamba install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`. And mamba says that `notebook` will be downgraded from 7.0.3 to 6.5.4